# Group Policy WMI Filter to Check if Windows Feature is Installed

Tags: group-policy, wmi

The following returns true for servers without the Server GUI installed:

```
WMIC PATH Win32_OptionalFeature WHERE "Caption = 'Microsoft-Windows-Server-Gui-Shell-Package-DisplayName' AND InstallState = 2"
```

However, my attempt to translate this into a WMI filter...

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_OptionalFeature WHERE Caption = Microsoft-Windows-Server-Gui-Shell-Package-DisplayName AND InstallState = 2
```

...failed with:

> A syntax error occurred trying to evaluate a query string.

...Which is fairly unhelpful.

What's the failure and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this as I was writing the question, and thought I'd share. I deceived myself when banging out the WMIC command and didn't think about the requirement for quoted values in the rather strict WQL syntax used here:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_OptionalFeature WHERE Caption = "Microsoft-Windows-Server-Gui-Shell-Package-DisplayName" AND InstallState = "2"
```

Boring solution, but there you have it. It drove me to drinking, so I thought I'd save someone else's future productivity time.

Don't let it stop you from drinking, though. That's plenty productive.